# Calculate with Javascript - first time of sum is NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit confused. I have some code and if I put a product into my cart, I'm calculating the sum of the prices.

This is my code:

```
function ware_cart_sum(){
  var cart_sum = parseInt(0);

  if($('.in_cart_products tr').length){
    $('.in_cart_products tr').each(function() {
      var value = parseInt($(this).find(".product_count_incart").val());
      var price = parseInt($(this).find(".td_price span").text());

      cart_sum = parseInt(cart_sum) + (parseInt(value) * parseInt(price));
    });
  }
  return cart_sum;
}
```

At the first time I get NaN. Var cart_sum = NaN.
When I do a page reload, the calculating is right and I get the right sum of my product_prices.

But why???

I logged all. The type of these 3 variables are "number". So why do I get NaN?

Is there a problem with the each? If there is only 1 product in there?

Hope I get some answers here..

Comment: How you are using `ware_cart_sum()`? And a recommendation always use radix with `parseInt('str', 10)`

Comment: there's a whole lot of unnecessary `parseInt()`'s parsing integer values into integer values in your code.

Comment: At least one of your `value` and `price` assignments get evaluated to `NaN`. Maybe `.product_count_incart` doesn't have a `value` or `.td_price span` contains something like `$10` or one of them are empty?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse to int the price? It never has cents, like a float, for instance?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: No, they are never empty. They also don't get a symbol. The span only contains a number as string. 

When I'm loggin them:

Value = type: number, 1
Price = type: number, 120

LuudJacobs I tried all, now I removed the unnecessary parseInt's.

Satpal I only use it like: ware_cart_sum(). 

I've tried the radix too (10), but I doesn't matter..

Comment: Can you create a JS bin/ plnkr example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine. See my code below.

```js
function ware_cart_sum() {
  var cart_sum = parseInt(0);

  if ($('.in_cart_products tr').length) {
    $('.in_cart_products tr').each(function() {
      var value = parseInt($(this).find(".product_count_incart").val());
      var price = parseInt($(this).find(".td_price span").text());

      cart_sum += (value * price);
    });
  }
  console.log(cart_sum);
$('#sum').text(cart_sum);
  return cart_sum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table class="in_cart_products">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="product_count_incart" value="1">
        <span class='td_price'>    <span>100</span> </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="product_count_incart" value="2">
        <span class='td_price'>    <span>50</span> </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>total: <span  id="sum">0</span><div>
  <button onclick="ware_cart_sum()">Calculate</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how it should work. But I still get "NaN". I really don't know why. Now my final solution is. I take the result of Ajax, and paste the hole table into my document. In php I have the same "sum" function. This works. I really don't know why Javascript gets "NaN". My student colleges also don't know. So the easiest way is - copy and paste the hole table. I just wanted to make this via JS.^^

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use parseInt repeatedly.
The problem might be in the way you are getting the value. val() only returns value for `select` , `textarea` and `input`. You can use `text()` to get the value from your html markup. 
In your case`val()` return empty string which you are converting to int, there's where you are getting NaN.
Not sure why your code works after refreshing.

Comment: Yes you're right. But in "value" I am selecting the input's value. In "price" I'm selecting html text in a span tag, which is only a number without any $, € or other symbols.